# import custom csv to custom table- magento 2

Tags: magento2, import, importexport, export

My requirement is import custom csv file to custom table.

please share hints and key points to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**note:** I get crystal clear explanation of custom import option from [this link](http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-programming-implement-import-with-import-xml)

Please first download the whole zip file from [this github link](https://github.com/ibnab/tut-magento2-import) then change the module name as per your requirement. Just alter the two files is enough to import your custom CSV to custom table.

**step1:** alter **app/code/vendor/module_name/etc/import.xml** from your download github folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_ImportExport:etc/import.xsd">
    <entity name="chennai_event" label="Chennai Event" model="Gworks\Chennaievent\Model\Import\CustomerGroup" behaviorModel="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Source\Import\Behavior\Basic" />
</config>
```

**step2:** then you should need to create model class as per mention in the above import.xml

**app/code/vendor/module_name/Model/Import/CustomerGroup.php**

```
<?php
namespace Gworks\Chennaievent\Model\Import;

use Gworks\Chennaievent\Model\Import\CustomerGroup\RowValidatorInterface as ValidatorInterface;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\ErrorProcessing\ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;

class CustomerGroup extends \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity
{

    const ID = 'id';
    const EVENTNAME = 'event_name';
    const IMGURL = 'event_imgurl';
    const BANNERIMGURL = 'event_bannerimgurl';
    const DESC = 'event_description';
    const LDESC = 'event_longdescription';
    const PLACE = 'event_place';
    const DATE = 'event_date';
    const GIFT = 'event_suggestgift';
    const TYPE = 'type';

    const TABLE_Entity = 'chennai_event';

    /**
     * Validation failure message template definitions
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_messageTemplates = [
    ValidatorInterface::ERROR_TITLE_IS_EMPTY => 'TITLE is empty',
    ];

     protected $_permanentAttributes = [self::ID];
    /**
     * If we should check column names
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $needColumnCheck = true;
    protected $groupFactory;
    /**
     * Valid column names
     *
     * @array
     */
    protected $validColumnNames = [
    self::ID,
    self::EVENTNAME,
    self::IMGURL,
    self::BANNERIMGURL,
    self::DESC,
    self::LDESC,
    self::PLACE,
    self::DATE,
    self::GIFT,
    self::TYPE,
    ];

    /**
     * Need to log in import history
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $logInHistory = true;

    protected $_validators = [];


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime
     */
    protected $_connection;
    protected $_resource;

    /**
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
    \Magento\ImportExport\Helper\Data $importExportData,
    \Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Import\Data $importData,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
    \Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Helper $resourceHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
    ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface $errorAggregator,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\GroupFactory $groupFactory
    ) {
    $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
    $this->_importExportData = $importExportData;
    $this->_resourceHelper = $resourceHelper;
    $this->_dataSourceModel = $importData;
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    $this->_connection = $resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
    $this->errorAggregator = $errorAggregator;
    $this->groupFactory = $groupFactory;
    }
    public function getValidColumnNames()
    {
    return $this->validColumnNames;
    }

    /**
     * Entity type code getter.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEntityTypeCode()
    {
    return 'chennai_event';
    }

    /**
     * Row validation.
     *
     * @param array $rowData
     * @param int $rowNum
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateRow(array $rowData, $rowNum)
    {

    $title = false;

    if (isset($this->_validatedRows[$rowNum])) {
        return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
    }

    $this->_validatedRows[$rowNum] = true;
    // BEHAVIOR_DELETE use specific validation logic
       // if (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_DELETE == $this->getBehavior()) {
        if (!isset($rowData[self::ID]) || empty($rowData[self::ID])) {
            $this->addRowError(ValidatorInterface::ERROR_TITLE_IS_EMPTY, $rowNum);
            return false;
        }

    return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
    }


    /**
     * Create Advanced price data from raw data.
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     * @return bool Result of operation.
     */
    protected function _importData()
    {
    if (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_DELETE == $this->getBehavior()) {
        $this->deleteEntity();
    } elseif (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE == $this->getBehavior()) {
        $this->replaceEntity();
    } elseif (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND == $this->getBehavior()) {
        $this->saveEntity();
    }

    return true;
    }
    /**
     * Save newsletter subscriber
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function saveEntity()
    {
    $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
    return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Replace newsletter subscriber
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function replaceEntity()
    {
    $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
    return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Deletes newsletter subscriber data from raw data.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function deleteEntity()
    {
    $listTitle = [];
    while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
        foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $rowData) {
            $this->validateRow($rowData, $rowNum);
            if (!$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum)) {
                $rowTtile = $rowData[self::ID];
                $listTitle[] = $rowTtile;
            }
            if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);
            }
        }
    }
    if ($listTitle) {
        $this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique($listTitle),self::TABLE_Entity);
    }
    return $this;
    }
 /**
     * Save and replace newsletter subscriber
     *
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    protected function saveAndReplaceEntity()
    {
    $behavior = $this->getBehavior();
    $listTitle = [];
    while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
        $entityList = [];
        foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $rowData) {
            if (!$this->validateRow($rowData, $rowNum)) {
                $this->addRowError(ValidatorInterface::ERROR_TITLE_IS_EMPTY, $rowNum);
                continue;
            }
            if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);
                continue;
            }

            $rowTtile= $rowData[self::ID];
            $listTitle[] = $rowTtile;
            $entityList[$rowTtile][] = [
              self::ID => $rowData[self::ID],
              self::EVENTNAME => $rowData[self::EVENTNAME],
                self::IMGURL => $rowData[self::IMGURL],
                self::BANNERIMGURL => $rowData[self::BANNERIMGURL],
                self::DESC => $rowData[self::DESC],
                self::LDESC => $rowData[self::LDESC],
                self::PLACE => $rowData[self::PLACE],
                self::DATE => $rowData[self::DATE],
                self::GIFT => $rowData[self::GIFT],
                self::TYPE => $rowData[self::TYPE],
            ];
        }
        if (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE == $behavior) {
            if ($listTitle) {
                if ($this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique(  $listTitle), self::TABLE_Entity)) {
                    $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList, self::TABLE_Entity);
                }
            }
        } elseif (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND == $behavior) {
            $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList, self::TABLE_Entity);
        }
    }
    return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Save product prices.
     *
     * @param array $priceData
     * @param string $table
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function saveEntityFinish(array $entityData, $table)
    {
    if ($entityData) {
        $tableName = $this->_connection->getTableName($table);
        $entityIn = [];
        foreach ($entityData as $id => $entityRows) {
                foreach ($entityRows as $row) {
                    $entityIn[] = $row;
                }
        }
        if ($entityIn) {
            $this->_connection->insertOnDuplicate($tableName, $entityIn,[
                self::ID,
                self::EVENTNAME,
                self::IMGURL,
                self::BANNERIMGURL,
                self::DESC,
                self::LDESC,
                self::PLACE,
                self::DATE,
                self::GIFT,
                self::TYPE
        ]);
        }
    }
    return $this;
    }
    protected function deleteEntityFinish(array $listTitle, $table)
    {
    if ($table && $listTitle) {
            try {
                $this->countItemsDeleted += $this->_connection->delete(
                    $this->_connection->getTableName($table),
                    $this->_connection->quoteInto('customer_group_code IN (?)', $listTitle)
                );
                return true;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return false;
            }

    } else {
        return false;
    }
    }
}
```

My table structure

[image: easy for your reference]

thats it, for any clarity related to this answer please mention in comment.

@Atish Goshwami answer also correct, Why am I update? because with my way I could achieve result within twenty minutes its simple way to done this.

Comment: Thanks Bilal, i got only little idea, can you please help me with this... I have a custom table..Now when i import csv by changing or deleting the product details, only the product ids of those updated products should be saved to table

Comment: I have implemented in Magento1x as shown here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127704/magento2-override-adminhtml-gui-controller

Comment: @SachinS did you resolved?  it is working like native magento 2 import function. I don't know magento 1.X :-). if you mention what is your specific problem, I will try to help.

Comment: Bilal, I want to add only the modified product ids into my custom table during import...i have explained the problem here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127903/problem-overriding-catalogimportexport-module, need help

Comment: Any suggestions @Bilal Usean

Comment: Hi @Bilal Usean, i have replicated the same way as u have done in ur post here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133936/import-custom-csv-to-custom-table-with-entity-id-not-saving   Only thing is i want  my product_ids also to be saved to my custom table..Need ur help here

Comment: alternate solution @sachin. while import, product id not create yet so you can save sku instead of product id. after that using this sku you can easily get the product id or whatever information you need related to product. I hope it helps :-)

Comment: Yes we can fetch other details using SKU after saving, but in Magento1x, during import entity_id was getting saved, i want the same to be implemented in 2x also

Comment: But how are we getting the entity_ids here in default Magentos ImportExport from this line... $this->skuProcessor->getNewSku($rowSku)['entity_id']

Comment: I need to work on your problem to figure out how to achieve I will be back to you :-)

Comment: getting the error regarding use Gworks\Chennaievent\Model\Import\CustomerGroup\RowValidatorInterface as ValidatorInterface;  can you please help me solving the issues.

Comment: Is there any way to same process for export custom model CSV? This is my detailed question. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229902/i-want-to-add-my-custom-entity-for-export-magento-2

Comment: @BilalUsean, can we use the above code to import custom CSV into custom table from customer account? Or is it only applicable to upload from Magento admin import/export?

Comment: Can we provide this option in custom module File upload in store configuration?

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest to extend the Magento 2's default import functionality.

To do that register a new module (lets say "Custom Import" for now)

Create a `module.xml` file at `app/code/Foo/CustomImport/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Foo_CustomPriceImport" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

Next create `import.xml` file at `app/code/Foo/CustomImport/etc/import.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_ImportExport:etc/import.xsd">
    <entity name="custom_import" label="Custom Import" model="Foo\CustomImport\Model\Import\CustomImport" behaviorModel="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Source\Import\Behavior\Basic" />
</config>
```

The entry `import.xml` will add a new option in the import page "Entity Type" dropdown (System > Data Transfer > Import)

now in the `import.xml` the xml attributes:

`behaviorModel`: Takes the class name of the model class responsible to handle the logic for the import

`label`: Label name of the dropdown option

`name`: name for the dropdown option value

[image: import page "Entity Type" dropdown]

Next we need to create the model file at `app/code/Foo/CustomImport/Model/Import/CustomPricing.php`

`class CustomImport extends \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity`

You can take the reference of the `Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport` to see the import logic.

Comment: Atish, i need your help in this link  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127704/magento2-override-adminhtml-gui-controller where i have a custom table, in which when i import csv products, those product ids should be saved in my custom table

Comment: @Atish, I followed the above-mentioned procedure, the check data functionality has worked, but after that, they show a button "Import" if I hit the button nothing is happening.could you pls share your thoughts

Comment: @senthil can you check the expection.log can see what is happening

Answer (score 3):

First, create an Import Button in your Ui-component File

**[vendor_name] \ [module_name] \view\adminhtml\ui_component**

***uiComponenetFileName.xml***

```
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
    
        <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/add</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
        </item>

         <item name="import" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">import</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Import Storelocatore</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">secondary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/dataimport/importdata</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
        </item>

    </item>
```

Now this Import Button Call Import Data Form

**[vendor_name] \ [module_name] \Controller\Adminhtml\Dataimport**

***Importdata.php***

```
<?php

namespace [vendor_name]\ [module_name] \Controller\Adminhtml\Dataimport;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Importdata extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    private $coreRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
    ) {                                 
       
       parent::__construct($context);
       $this->coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $rowData = $this->_objectManager->create('[vendor_name] \ [module_name] \Model\Locator');
        $this->coreRegistry->register('row_data', $rowData);
        $resultPage = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Import Locator Data'));
        return $resultPage;
    }

    // used for acl.xml
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('[vendor_name]_[module_name]::add_datalocation');
    }
}
```

create a Layout File that Calls your Block File

**[vendor_name] \ [module_name] \view\adminhtml\layout**

***[controller_name]_dataimport_importdata.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
           <block class="[vendor_name] \ [module_name] \Block\Adminhtml\Dataimport\Importdata" name="importdata_locator" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

create a block File for Import Data Form

**[vendor_name] \ [module_name] \Block\Adminhtml\Dataimport**

***Importdata.php***

```
<?php 

namespace [vendor_name] \ [module_name] \Block\Adminhtml\Dataimport;

class Importdata extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container
{
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_objectId = 'row_id';
        $this->_blockGroup = '[module_name]_[vendor_name]';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_dataimport';
        parent::_construct();
        $this->buttonList->remove('back');
        $this->buttonList->update('save', 'label', __('Import'));
        $this->buttonList->remove('reset');

        $this->addButton(
                    'backhome',
                    [
                        'label' => __('Back'),
                        'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->getUrl('[route_name] / [controller_name] /index')),
                        'class' => 'back',
                        'level' => -2
                    ]
                );


    }

    
    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        return __('Import Location Data');
    }
    
    protected function _isAllowedAction($resourceId)
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed($resourceId);
    }

    
    public function getFormActionUrl()
    {
        if ($this->hasFormActionUrl()) {
            return $this->getData('form_action_url');
        }
        return $this->getUrl('[route_name] / dataimport/save');
    }
}
```

the above file call import form

**[vendor_name] \ [module_name] \Block\Adminhtml\Dataimport\Edit**

***Form.php***

```
<?php

namespace [vendor_name] \ [module_name] \Block\Adminhtml\Dataimport\Edit;

use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository; 

class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{
    protected $_assetRepo;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo,
        array $data = []
    ) {   
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }


    protected function _prepareForm()
    {   
        $path = $this->_assetRepo->getUrl("[vendor_name]_[module_name]::img/[vendor_name]_[module_name]_Sample_File.csv");

        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('row_data');

        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            ['data' => [
                            'id' => 'edit_form',
                            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                            'action' => $this->getData('action'),
                            'method' => 'post'
                        ]
            ]
        );

        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('datalocation_');

           $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
                'base_fieldset',
                ['legend' => __('Import Location '), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
            );

       $importdata_script =  $fieldset->addField(
            'importdata',
            'file', 
                array(
                        'label'     => 'Upload File',
                        'required'  => true,
                        'name'      => 'importdata',  
                        'note' => 'Allow File type: .csv and .xls', 
                     )
        );

        $importdata_script->setAfterElementHtml("   
        
        <span id='sample-file-span' ><a id='sample-file-link' href='".$path."'  >Download Sample File</a></span>

            <script type=\"text/javascript\">

            document.getElementById('[route_name]_importdata').onchange = function () { 

                var fileInput = document.getElementById('[route_name]_importdata');

                var filePath = fileInput.value;

                var allowedExtensions = /(\.csv|\.xls)$/i; 

                if(!allowedExtensions.exec(filePath))
                {
                    alert('Please upload file having extensions .csv or .xls only.');
                    fileInput.value = '';
                }

            };

            </script>"
        );


        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
  
}
```

this imported form checks whether a file is valid or not, now create a file that reads your uploaded file and inserts it into the table.

**[vendor_name] \ [module_name] \Controller\Adminhtml\Dataimport***

***Save.php***

```
<?php

namespace [vendor_name]\[module_name]\Controller\Adminhtml\Dataimport;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface; 


class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    protected $fileSystem;

    protected $uploaderFactory;

    protected $request;

    protected $adapterFactory;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        AdapterFactory $adapterFactory
        
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->fileSystem = $fileSystem;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->adapterFactory = $adapterFactory;
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    { 

         if ( (isset($_FILES['importdata']['name'])) && ($_FILES['importdata']['name'] != '') ) 
         {
            try 
           {    
                $uploaderFactory = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'importdata']);
                $uploaderFactory->setAllowedExtensions(['csv', 'xls']);
                $uploaderFactory->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploaderFactory->setFilesDispersion(true);

                $mediaDirectory = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
                $destinationPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('[vendor_name]_[module_name]_IMPORTDATA');

                $result = $uploaderFactory->save($destinationPath);

                if (!$result) 
                   {
                     throw new LocalizedException
                     (
                        __('File cannot be saved to path: $1', $destinationPath)
                     );

                   }
                else
                    {   
                        $imagePath = '[vendor_name]_[module_name]_IMPORTDATA'.$result['file'];

                        $mediaDirectory = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
                        
                        $destinationfilePath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($imagePath);

                        /* file read operation */

                        $f_object = fopen($destinationfilePath, "r");
                        
                        $column = fgetcsv($f_object);
                        
                        // column name must be the same as the Sample filename 

                        if($f_object)
                        {
                            if( ($column[0] == 'Col_name_1') && ($column[1] == 'Col_name_2') && ($column[2] == 'Col_name_3') && ($column[3] == 'Col_name_4') && ($column[4] == 'Col_name_5') )
                            {   

                                $count = 0;

                                while (($columns = fgetcsv($f_object)) !== FALSE) 
                                {
                            
                                    $rowData = $this->_objectManager->create('VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Storelocator');

                                    if($columns[0] != 'Col_name_1')// unique Name like Primary key
                                    {   
                                        $count++;

                                    /// here this are all the Getter Setter Method which are call to set value 
                                    // the auto increment column name not used to set value 
                                    
                                        $rowData->setCol_name_1($columns[1]);

                                        $rowData->setCol_name_2($columns[2]);

                                        $rowData->setCol_name_3($columns[3]);

                                        $rowData->setCol_name_4($columns[4]);

                                        $rowData->setCol_name_5($columns[5]);

                                        $rowData->save();   

                                    }

                                } 
                                
                            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 record(s) have been Added.', $count));
                            $this->_redirect('[route_name]/[controller_name]/index');
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $this->messageManager->addError(__("invalid Formated File"));
                                $this->_redirect('[route_name]/dataimport/importdata');
                            }

                        } 
                        else
                        {
                            $this->messageManager->addError(__("File hase been empty"));
                            $this->_redirect('[route_name]/dataimport/importdata');
                        }
               
                    }                   

           } 
           catch (\Exception $e) 
          {   
               $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
               $this->_redirect('[controller_name]/dataimport/importdata');
          }

         }
         else
         {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__("Please try again."));
            $this->_redirect('[controller_name]/dataimport/importdata');
         }
    }
}
```

Now you can click on the Import Button and upload the .csv file and import data.

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: I have used this module and working fine but download sample csv is not working its throws an error like 
Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/TML_Dealers/img/example.csv'
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:263]
#2 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/static.php:13]
</pre>
please help on this.. tq in advance

Comment: where is Dolphin\Storelocator\Model\Storelocator file?

Comment: it's your Model file from where to store and retrieve data, vendoreName\ModuleName\Model\YourModelName

Answer (score 1):

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/etc**

**db_schema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="custom_import">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="entity_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Entity Id" identity="true" />
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="name" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Product Name"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="duration" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Duration"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="CUSTOM_IMPORT_ID_PRIMARY">
            <column name="entity_id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

[image]

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/etc**

**import.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_ImportExport:etc/import.xsd">
    <entity name="custom_import" label="Custom Import" model="VendoreName\CustomDataImport\Model\Import\CustomImport" behaviorModel="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Source\Import\Behavior\Basic" />
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/Files/Sample**

**custom_import.csv**

```
entity_id,name,duration
,"Name 1",90
2,"Name 3",120
```

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\SampleFileProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="samples" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_import" xsi:type="string">VendoreName_CustomDataImport</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/Model/Import**

**CustomImport.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\CustomDataImport\Model\Import;

use Exception;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data as JsonHelper;
use Magento\ImportExport\Helper\Data as ImportHelper;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\ErrorProcessing\ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Helper;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Import\Data;

/**
 * Class Courses
 */
class CustomImport extends AbstractEntity
{
    const ENTITY_CODE = 'custom_import';
    const TABLE = 'custom_import';
    const ENTITY_ID_COLUMN = 'entity_id';

    /**
     * If we should check column names
     */
    protected $needColumnCheck = true;

    /**
     * Need to log in import history
     */
    protected $logInHistory = true;

    /**
     * Permanent entity columns.
     */
    protected $_permanentAttributes = [
        'entity_id',
    ];

    /**
     * Valid column names
     */
    protected $validColumnNames = [
        'entity_id',
        'name',
        'duration',
    ];

    /**
     * @var AdapterInterface
     */
    protected $connection;

    /**
     * @var ResourceConnection
     */
    private $resource;

    /**
     * Courses constructor.
     *
     * @param JsonHelper $jsonHelper
     * @param ImportHelper $importExportData
     * @param Data $importData
     * @param ResourceConnection $resource
     * @param Helper $resourceHelper
     * @param ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface $errorAggregator
     */
    public function __construct(
        JsonHelper $jsonHelper,
        ImportHelper $importExportData,
        Data $importData,
        ResourceConnection $resource,
        Helper $resourceHelper,
        ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface $errorAggregator
    ) {
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->_importExportData = $importExportData;
        $this->_resourceHelper = $resourceHelper;
        $this->_dataSourceModel = $importData;
        $this->resource = $resource;
        $this->connection = $resource->getConnection(ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
        $this->errorAggregator = $errorAggregator;
        $this->initMessageTemplates();
    }

    /**
     * Entity type code getter.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEntityTypeCode()
    {
        return static::ENTITY_CODE;
    }

    /**
     * Get available columns
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getValidColumnNames(): array
    {
        return $this->validColumnNames;
    }

    /**
     * Row validation
     *
     * @param array $rowData
     * @param int $rowNum
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateRow(array $rowData, $rowNum): bool
    {
        $name = $rowData['name'] ?? '';
        $duration = (int) $rowData['duration'] ?? 0;

        if (!$name) {
            $this->addRowError('NameIsRequired', $rowNum);
        }

        if (!$duration) {
            $this->addRowError('DurationIsRequired', $rowNum);
        }

        if (isset($this->_validatedRows[$rowNum])) {
            return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
        }

        $this->_validatedRows[$rowNum] = true;

        return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
    }

    /**
     * Init Error Messages
     */
    private function initMessageTemplates()
    {
        $this->addMessageTemplate(
            'NameIsRequired',
            __('The name cannot be empty.')
        );
        $this->addMessageTemplate(
            'DurationIsRequired',
            __('Duration should be greater than 0.')
        );
    }

    /**
     * Import data
     *
     * @return bool
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected function _importData(): bool
    {
        switch ($this->getBehavior()) {
            case Import::BEHAVIOR_DELETE:
                $this->deleteEntity();
                break;
            case Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE:
                $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
                break;
            case Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND:
                $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Delete entities
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function deleteEntity(): bool
    {
        $rows = [];
        while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
            foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $rowData) {
                $this->validateRow($rowData, $rowNum);

                if (!$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum)) {
                    $rowId = $rowData[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN];
                    $rows[] = $rowId;
                }

                if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                    $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);
                }
            }
        }

        if ($rows) {
            return $this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique($rows));
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Save and replace entities
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function saveAndReplaceEntity()
    {
        $behavior = $this->getBehavior();
        $rows = [];
        while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
            $entityList = [];

            foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $row) {
                if (!$this->validateRow($row, $rowNum)) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                    $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);

                    continue;
                }

                $rowId = $row[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN];
                $rows[] = $rowId;
                $columnValues = [];

                foreach ($this->getAvailableColumns() as $columnKey) {
                    $columnValues[$columnKey] = $row[$columnKey];
                }

                $entityList[$rowId][] = $columnValues;
                $this->countItemsCreated += (int) !isset($row[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN]);
                $this->countItemsUpdated += (int) isset($row[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN]);
            }
            if (Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE === $behavior) {
                if ($rows && $this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique($rows))) {
                    $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList);
                }
            } elseif (Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND === $behavior) {
                $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Save entities
     *
     * @param array $entityData
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function saveEntityFinish(array $entityData): bool
    {
        if ($entityData) {
            $tableName = $this->connection->getTableName(static::TABLE);
            $rows = [];

            foreach ($entityData as $entityRows) {
                foreach ($entityRows as $row) {
                    $rows[] = $row;
                }
            }

            if ($rows) {
                $this->connection->insertOnDuplicate($tableName, $rows, $this->getAvailableColumns());

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete entities
     *
     * @param array $entityIds
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function deleteEntityFinish(array $entityIds): bool
    {
        if ($entityIds) {
            try {
                $this->countItemsDeleted += $this->connection->delete(
                    $this->connection->getTableName(static::TABLE),
                    $this->connection->quoteInto(static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN . ' IN (?)', $entityIds)
                );

                return true;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get available columns
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getAvailableColumns(): array
    {
        return $this->validColumnNames;
    }
}
```