# magento2 insert error during csv import

Tags: magento2

I want to insert the entity_id of my modified products while csv import into my custom table.

My custom table "tgs_queue" columns : (id, product_id)         //id-primary key

In CatalogImportExport saveProductEntity() i tried something like this:

```
 public function saveProductEntity(array $entityRowsIn, array $entityRowsUp)
{
   //custom code
    if (!$tableName) {
        $tableName = $this->_resourceFactory->create()->getTable('tgs_queue');
    }

    if ($entityRowsUp) {
        $this->_connection->insertOnDuplicate($entityTable,$entityRowsUp, ['updated_at']);

      //custom code
        $this->_connection->insertOnDuplicate($tableName, $entityRowsUp);
    }
```

I get the error for updated_at' as

```
General system exception happened
Additional data: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list', query was: INSERT INTO `tgs_queue` (`updated_at`,`entity_id`) VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `updated_at` = VALUES(`updated_at`), `entity_id` = VALUES(`entity_id`)
```

Whats the proper way of Inserting my data to custom table during import csv?

Comment: This should help http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114525/import-custom-csv-to-custom-table-magento-2/114536

Comment: I tried that Atish, i want to insert product id into my custom table on csv import...

Comment: Do you want only the newly inserted product entity ids or all the product entity ids in your custom table ?

Comment: Only the modified product details's product ids during import to my custom table

Comment: Magento fires an event called `catalog_product_import_finish_before` after the product import is completed, `vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product.php:890`. You can use an event observer to add logic after the import process