# Import custom csv to custom table with entity_id not saving

Tags: magento2

To save the entity_id in my custom table on csv import.

**Vendor\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product.php**

```
class Product extends \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity
{
    const SKU = 'sku';
    const COL_ENTITY_ID = 'entity_id';

    const TABLE_Entity = 'temp_tgs';

    /**
 * Validation failure message template definitions
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_messageTemplates = [
    ValidatorInterface::ERROR_PRODUCTID_IS_EMPTY => 'TITLE is empty',
];

 protected $_permanentAttributes = [self::SKU];
/**
 * If we should check column names
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $needColumnCheck = true;
protected $groupFactory;
/**
 * Valid column names
 *
 * @array
 */
protected $validColumnNames = [
   // self::COL_ENTITY_ID,
    self::SKU,
    //self::NAME,
];

/**
 * Need to log in import history
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $logInHistory = true;

protected $_validators = [];


/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime
 */
protected $_connection;
protected $_resource;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
    \Magento\ImportExport\Helper\Data $importExportData,
    \Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Import\Data $importData,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
    \Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Helper $resourceHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
    ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface $errorAggregator,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\GroupFactory $groupFactory
) {
    $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
    $this->_importExportData = $importExportData;
    $this->_resourceHelper = $resourceHelper;
    $this->_dataSourceModel = $importData;
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    $this->_connection = $resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
    $this->errorAggregator = $errorAggregator;
    $this->groupFactory = $groupFactory;
}
public function getValidColumnNames()
{
    return $this->validColumnNames;
}

/**
 * Entity type code getter.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEntityTypeCode()
{
    return 'my_import';
}

/**
 * Row validation.
 *
 * @param array $rowData
 * @param int $rowNum
 * @return bool
 */
public function validateRow(array $rowData, $rowNum)
{

    $title = false;

    if (isset($this->_validatedRows[$rowNum])) {
        return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
    }

    $this->_validatedRows[$rowNum] = true;
    // BEHAVIOR_DELETE use specific validation logic
   // if (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_DELETE == $this->getBehavior()) {
        if (!isset($rowData[self::SKU]) || empty($rowData[self::SKU]) ) {
            $this->addRowError(ValidatorInterface::ERROR_PRODUCTID_IS_EMPTY, $rowNum);
            return false;
        }

    return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
}

/**
 * Create Advanced price data from raw data.
 *
 * @throws \Exception
 * @return bool Result of operation.
 */
protected function _importData()
{
    if (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_DELETE == $this->getBehavior()) {
        $this->deleteEntity();
    } elseif (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE == $this->getBehavior()) {
        $this->replaceEntity();
    } elseif (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND == $this->getBehavior()) {
        $this->saveEntity();
    }

    return true;
}
/**
 * Save newsletter subscriber
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function saveEntity()
{
    $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
    return $this;
}
/**
 * Replace newsletter subscriber
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function replaceEntity()
{
    $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
    return $this;
}

protected function saveAndReplaceEntity()
{
    $behavior = $this->getBehavior();
    $listTitle = [];
    while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
        $entityList = [];
        foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $rowData) {
            if (!$this->validateRow($rowData, $rowNum)) {
                $this->addRowError(ValidatorInterface::ERROR_PRODUCTID_IS_EMPTY, $rowNum);
                continue;
            }
            if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);
                continue;
            }

            $rowTtile= $rowData[self::SKU];
            $listTitle[] = $rowTtile;
            $entityList[$rowTtile][] = [
              self::SKU => $rowData[self::SKU],
              //self::COL_ENTITY_ID => $rowData[self::COL_ENTITY_ID],
            ];
        }
        if (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE == $behavior) {
            if ($listTitle) {
                if ($this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique($listTitle), self::TABLE_Entity)) {
                    $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList, self::TABLE_Entity);
                }
            }
        } elseif (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND == $behavior) {
            $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList, self::TABLE_Entity);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}

protected function saveEntityFinish(array $entityData, $table)
{
    if ($entityData) {
        $tableName = $this->_connection->getTableName($table);
        $entityIn = [];
        foreach ($entityData as $id => $entityRows) {
                foreach ($entityRows as $row) {
                    $entityIn[] = $row;
                }
        }

        if ($entityIn) {
            $this->_connection->insertOnDuplicate($tableName, $entityIn,[
            self::SKU,
            self::COL_ENTITY_ID,   //here i need my imported productids to be saved to temp_tgs table
        ]);
       }
    }
    return $this; 

}
```

**My table structure:**

[image]

Im importing csv with columns only SKU as of now.(Following Magentos default import file, which has no product ids)

[image]

Problem is my sku is saving but i need the product ids of the imported products to be saved.

Im getting :

Additional data: Notice: Undefined index: entity_id in Vendor\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product.php on line 216

ie here:  (if i uncomment the line)
self::COL_ENTITY_ID => $rowData[self::COL_ENTITY_ID],

Comment: hi !! can you reply your answer ?

Comment: import custom product attribute from csv to custom table- magento 2.1 if yyou have answer reply to my question Plz

Comment: @Sushivam, I followed (http://www.blogtreat.com/how-to-import-csv-file-to-custom-module-table-in-magento-2/) it's creating new filed, and while upload the CSV it's validated, after that if I hit the "import" button nothing is happening simply loading... in console, there is no request for the import button

Answer (score 0):

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/etc**

**db_schema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="custom_import">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="entity_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Entity Id" identity="true" />
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="name" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Product Name"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="duration" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Duration"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="CUSTOM_IMPORT_ID_PRIMARY">
            <column name="entity_id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

[image]

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/etc**

**import.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_ImportExport:etc/import.xsd">
    <entity name="custom_import" label="Custom Import" model="VendoreName\CustomDataImport\Model\Import\CustomImport" behaviorModel="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Source\Import\Behavior\Basic" />
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/Files/Sample**

**custom_import.csv**

```
entity_id,name,duration
,"Name 1",90
2,"Name 3",120
```

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\SampleFileProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="samples" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_import" xsi:type="string">VendoreName_CustomDataImport</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/CustomDataImport/Model/Import**

**CustomImport.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\CustomDataImport\Model\Import;

use Exception;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data as JsonHelper;
use Magento\ImportExport\Helper\Data as ImportHelper;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\ErrorProcessing\ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Helper;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Import\Data;

/**
 * Class Courses
 */
class CustomImport extends AbstractEntity
{
    const ENTITY_CODE = 'custom_import';
    const TABLE = 'custom_import';
    const ENTITY_ID_COLUMN = 'entity_id';

    /**
     * If we should check column names
     */
    protected $needColumnCheck = true;

    /**
     * Need to log in import history
     */
    protected $logInHistory = true;

    /**
     * Permanent entity columns.
     */
    protected $_permanentAttributes = [
        'entity_id',
    ];

    /**
     * Valid column names
     */
    protected $validColumnNames = [
        'entity_id',
        'name',
        'duration',
    ];

    /**
     * @var AdapterInterface
     */
    protected $connection;

    /**
     * @var ResourceConnection
     */
    private $resource;

    /**
     * Courses constructor.
     *
     * @param JsonHelper $jsonHelper
     * @param ImportHelper $importExportData
     * @param Data $importData
     * @param ResourceConnection $resource
     * @param Helper $resourceHelper
     * @param ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface $errorAggregator
     */
    public function __construct(
        JsonHelper $jsonHelper,
        ImportHelper $importExportData,
        Data $importData,
        ResourceConnection $resource,
        Helper $resourceHelper,
        ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface $errorAggregator
    ) {
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->_importExportData = $importExportData;
        $this->_resourceHelper = $resourceHelper;
        $this->_dataSourceModel = $importData;
        $this->resource = $resource;
        $this->connection = $resource->getConnection(ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
        $this->errorAggregator = $errorAggregator;
        $this->initMessageTemplates();
    }

    /**
     * Entity type code getter.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEntityTypeCode()
    {
        return static::ENTITY_CODE;
    }

    /**
     * Get available columns
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getValidColumnNames(): array
    {
        return $this->validColumnNames;
    }

    /**
     * Row validation
     *
     * @param array $rowData
     * @param int $rowNum
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateRow(array $rowData, $rowNum): bool
    {
        $name = $rowData['name'] ?? '';
        $duration = (int) $rowData['duration'] ?? 0;

        if (!$name) {
            $this->addRowError('NameIsRequired', $rowNum);
        }

        if (!$duration) {
            $this->addRowError('DurationIsRequired', $rowNum);
        }

        if (isset($this->_validatedRows[$rowNum])) {
            return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
        }

        $this->_validatedRows[$rowNum] = true;

        return !$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum);
    }

    /**
     * Init Error Messages
     */
    private function initMessageTemplates()
    {
        $this->addMessageTemplate(
            'NameIsRequired',
            __('The name cannot be empty.')
        );
        $this->addMessageTemplate(
            'DurationIsRequired',
            __('Duration should be greater than 0.')
        );
    }

    /**
     * Import data
     *
     * @return bool
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected function _importData(): bool
    {
        switch ($this->getBehavior()) {
            case Import::BEHAVIOR_DELETE:
                $this->deleteEntity();
                break;
            case Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE:
                $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
                break;
            case Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND:
                $this->saveAndReplaceEntity();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Delete entities
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function deleteEntity(): bool
    {
        $rows = [];
        while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
            foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $rowData) {
                $this->validateRow($rowData, $rowNum);

                if (!$this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum)) {
                    $rowId = $rowData[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN];
                    $rows[] = $rowId;
                }

                if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                    $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);
                }
            }
        }

        if ($rows) {
            return $this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique($rows));
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Save and replace entities
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function saveAndReplaceEntity()
    {
        $behavior = $this->getBehavior();
        $rows = [];
        while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
            $entityList = [];

            foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $row) {
                if (!$this->validateRow($row, $rowNum)) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                    $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);

                    continue;
                }

                $rowId = $row[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN];
                $rows[] = $rowId;
                $columnValues = [];

                foreach ($this->getAvailableColumns() as $columnKey) {
                    $columnValues[$columnKey] = $row[$columnKey];
                }

                $entityList[$rowId][] = $columnValues;
                $this->countItemsCreated += (int) !isset($row[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN]);
                $this->countItemsUpdated += (int) isset($row[static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN]);
            }
            if (Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE === $behavior) {
                if ($rows && $this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique($rows))) {
                    $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList);
                }
            } elseif (Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND === $behavior) {
                $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Save entities
     *
     * @param array $entityData
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function saveEntityFinish(array $entityData): bool
    {
        if ($entityData) {
            $tableName = $this->connection->getTableName(static::TABLE);
            $rows = [];

            foreach ($entityData as $entityRows) {
                foreach ($entityRows as $row) {
                    $rows[] = $row;
                }
            }

            if ($rows) {
                $this->connection->insertOnDuplicate($tableName, $rows, $this->getAvailableColumns());

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete entities
     *
     * @param array $entityIds
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function deleteEntityFinish(array $entityIds): bool
    {
        if ($entityIds) {
            try {
                $this->countItemsDeleted += $this->connection->delete(
                    $this->connection->getTableName(static::TABLE),
                    $this->connection->quoteInto(static::ENTITY_ID_COLUMN . ' IN (?)', $entityIds)
                );

                return true;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get available columns
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getAvailableColumns(): array
    {
        return $this->validColumnNames;
    }
}
```