# During magento 2 import How to import some data from csv to custom table?

Tags: magento2

During the magento product import some of the data or column in csv file need to import in my custom table.
Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114525/import-custom-csv-to-custom-table-magento-2?rq=1

Comment: This link is custom csv and custom table but i need default magento product import at this time i need only sku column to import my custom table also

Comment: can anyone give me how to ideahow to acheive this