# magento2 product import error : Call to a member function getData() on nul

Tags: magento2, import

I tried implement import by Msquare answer from here  [import custom csv to custom table- magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114525/import-custom-csv-to-custom-table-magento-2)

But I getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getData() on null in (...) app/code/PetTheme/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Dataimport/Edit/Form.php:82 Stack trace: #0
```

this is this line:

```
$form->setValues($model->getData());
```

Any ideas what was wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

probably $model is empty or dont have data. There is line

```
$model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('row_data');
```

Use xdebug. Check what is get from this registry.

This is set in file Importdata

```
$this->coreRegistry->register('row_data', $rowData);
```

Check what is saved there ($rowData).

Also $rowData should contain object `[vendor_name] \ [module_name] \Model\Locator`
What is it? Is it created correctly? Is it correct class?