# how to add import & Export functionality to custom grid in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, importexport

I don't have any idea to do import and export functionality in Magento 2 for my custom module grid. Kindly help and suggest me some solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can added this code into the ui files so it added export button on your grid.

```
<exportButton name="export_button">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">sales_order_grid.sales_order_grid.sales_order_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
 </exportButton>
```

**NOTE:**

you need to replace `sales_order_grid` with your provider.

Comment: i am asking for my custom admin grid.. the answer you provided it for sales module

Comment: Read the note, where I mention what you want to replace in above code.

Comment: Shall i add this code inside my UI component file's <listing> tag

Comment: Yes you need to add the code there.

Comment: export is working...kindly help me in import functionality

Comment: check this link how to import :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114525/import-custom-csv-to-custom-table-magento-2

Comment: @SUBBULAKSHMIG above answer help, please upvote and accept it as solution, so it will help other in community.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya and Mohit  kindly help me in importing to custom table with Field Name instead of attribute code(example: First Name instead of first_name)

Comment: @MohitPatel kindly help me in importing to custom table with Field Name instead of attribute code(example: First Name instead of first_name)